# Firefox 17 reports created DOM element (HTMLObjectElement) as function when using "typeof"

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, object, typeof

I have a flash object (HTMLObjectElement) created (with jQuery) and added it to the DOM. That is working OK in all browsers.
This object is saved/stored in a variable called "o.data.cam". Other functions checking this variable if it is valid.

For example:

```
if( typeof o.data.cam == "object")
 { do this }
```

This is working OK in all browsers EXCEPT firefox. `o.data.cam` is a function instead of an object. 
That is a strange behaviour i think, because the object is created, why is this reported as function?

In Firefox 17.0.1 (latest) a created HTMLObjectElement (object tag) returns [object HTMLObjectElement] when dump it.
I can understand this (?), because it can be same as a native function (protected), for example like a native function => [native function]. Otherwise a bit strange because most of the DOM-elements can be inspected so why not his one?

But there are some differences to notice when comparing to other browsers:

```
                        Firefox                       Chrome     MSIE      Opera
___________________________________________________________________________________________
dump o.data.cam             [object HTMLObjectElement]    Object*    Object*   Object*
typeof o.data.cam           "function"                   "Object"   "Object"  "Object"
typeof HTMLObjectElement    "object"                     "function" "Object"  "function"
```

- (asterisk) = prints Object tree

NOTES:
- Between quotes is a string, a "typeof" result.

The typeof evaluation returns in all browsers "Object" (except Firefox), which is in my opinion correct, 
because when it is a function and created as class (new function) it must be reported as object (i think?)

My question is:
Is this a bug or do i missing something?

**EDIT: Created this function to check if it is a valid DOM element. Is it safe to do it this way? Now Firefox returns true.**

```
function isDOM(oo)
{ 
  if( oo )
  {
   if( typeof oo instanceof jQuery )
    { return !!oo[0]; }
   if( typeof oo == 'object' || typeof oo == 'function' )
    { return ( typeof oo.tagName == 'string' && oo.tagName.length > 0 ); }
  }
  return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the EcmaScript spec, all objects with a [[Call]] internal method must return "function" for typeof.

Instances of HTMLObjectElement can have a [[Call]] internal method, because plug-ins can make the object they're instantiated for callable.

So the only question is whether the object should always be callable and throw if the plug-in doesn't want to be called or whether it should dynamically change type between "object" and "function" depending on what the plug-in is doing.  There's also the third option of just ignoring the spec and reporting "object" even though there is a [[Call]], I guess.

Firefox does the former: always have a [[Call]], so typeof reports "function".  The other browsers are presumably either making [[Call]] appear and disappear dynamically or flat out violating the spec.

Comment: Thanks for your "clear" answer. That's a strange thing actually because a it is very difficult to detect if a object is a native one or real object. But, see my EDIT in the question. What do you think, solid solution or have you better idea's how to detect DOM elements cross-browser?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to tell apart "native" and "real" objects (whatever that even means)?  It's hard to evaluate your proposed solution without understanding what the goal is.  Is there a reason that `oo instanceof Node` doesn't do what you want, for example?

Comment: With native i mean that it is native code like a native function. For example when it is not possible to traverse or dump. That is native, something that belongs to the browser that is compiled natively. I can imagine that DOM elements it object is native, so you can not traverse or dump it. This is a real object in my perspective. When you create object in javascript it's only a object when it's created with a new constructor, otherwise its a function. But my major goal was to detect if variable is assigned and valid (DOM object). I was very surprised Firefox returns a DOM object as function

Comment: You can "traverse" Element objects just like any other object...  And no, there are lots of things in JS that are objects but not created with "new".

Comment: I know. But well, i never notice this before in firefox: typeof [HTMLObjectElement] == "function", is this changed in the latest version? Which browser is right in your opinion, the one that returns "object" or the one (Firefox) that returns "Object"? Just curiosity.

Comment: Which browser is correct depends on the exact semantics of when `<object>` is callable, which are not actually defined anywhere.  So they might all be correct, if they have different callability behavior for it.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the previous comment, "Object"must be "function"in the last sentence.