# Why doesn't underscore use typeof for detecting functions?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Add some isType methods: isArguments, isFunction, isString, isNumber, isDate, isRegExp, isError.
  _.each(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number', 'Date', 'RegExp', 'Error'], function(name) {
    _['is' + name] = function(obj) {
      return toString.call(obj) === '[object ' + name + ']';
    };
  });
```

I can understand why toString is used in these other cases, but

```
typeof function(){}
```

and

```
typeof new Function()
```

will return `function`

is there a use case that I am missing.

typeof should be faster and just as accurate in this case.

Comment: Underscore doesn't necessarily aim for speed. In this case, it's just *simpler* to add the `Function` name to the list of types.

Comment: There were bugs in some older browsers that would wrongly return `"function"` when `typeof` was applied to RegExp objects and some host objects.

Comment: in (older?) IE, window.alert() is an object according to typeof

Answer (score 3):

**Faster, yes, but it turns out to be not *quite* as accurate in practice.**

Although `typeof obj === 'function'` works in *most* cases, **some browsers do strange things in the edge cases, especially with native objects**. [There are a few questions here that go over some of the more bizarre cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873684/firefox-17-reports-created-dom-element-htmlobjectelement-as-function-when-usin) (and they're *really* bizarre, but they're out there): things like elements containing objects from plugins and such. The end result is that **there are a very few object/browser combinations out there that get this wrong in a couple of cases: when using `typeof`, either they detect as functions when they shouldn't, or they don't detect as functions when they should**.

For most code, this doesn't matter much. Like I said, we're talking about edge cases here. But libraries like Underscore can't afford to be wrong in the edge cases: they need to be sure they get it right in every case, even if the browser gets it wrong. And for whatever reason, even the browsers that get `typeof` wrong all seem to get `Object.prototype.toString(obj)` right. **So Underscore uses that trick, because it's the simplest method that works everywhere**. It also dovetails well with cases like `Array`, where you *have to* use this method because `typeof` just plain doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore uses a method that is consistent so as to avoid micro-optimization and improve readability and compressibility.

Treating `_.isFunction` differently for the sake of a couple microseconds doesn't make sense unless `_.isFunction` is an actual bottleneck in actual code.

Comment: what about the frame issue that was mentioned earlier and removed, is this not valid?

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com, there's a reason the (incorrect) answer was removed.

Comment: So, I think the answer is more so that it will fail in some browsers for regular expressions.  This fits its wrong behavior pattern with array and null as well.