# Why type of <object> is a function?

Tags: javascript, html, object, tags

I was wonder by that when worked with chrome devtools.
But it seems that typeof `<object>` is a "function". 

I haven't found any explanation or references.

Here is the simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/fez34zbf/

HTML:

```
<object></object>
<video></video>
```

JS:

```
console.log(typeof document.querySelector('object'));
console.log(typeof document.querySelector('video'));
```

console results will be:

```
function 
object
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the question is, *what type of function is an `HTMLObjectElement` instance?*

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873684/firefox-17-reports-created-dom-element-htmlobjectelement-as-function-when-usin, but Till's answer seems more extensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned typeof must return `"function"` for all Objects that have a `[[Call]]` internal method.([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)). So the interesting part is that instances of `HTMLObjectElement` for some reason have a `[[Call]]` internal method.

There are bug reports for this for [firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=296858) as well as [chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=568448). While there are no replies on the firefox issue on the chrome issue there is an explanation where `[[Call]]` gets added to `HTMLObjectElement`

> Yes, that's correct. SetCallAsFunctionHandler() makes the object callable according to EcmaScript, hence we have to return "function" for typeof.

`SetCallAsFunctionHandler` seems to be some implementation detail in v8. According to the issue chrome used to report `object` as the `typeof` instances of `HTMLObjectElement` but they changed it to be compatible with firefox.

---

Now why is there a `[[Call]]` internal method on `HTMLObjectElement`?  As [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875674) implies this seems to be used by some plugins. `HTMLObjectElement` is used by plugins ( e.g. flash ). And some of these plugins probably except input using this function.

Looking at the [source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/out/Debug/gen/blink/bindings/core/v8/V8HTMLEmbedElement.cpp?q=SetCallAsFunctionHandler+file:blink%7CWebKit&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=299) [code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/bindings/core/v8/custom/V8HTMLPlugInElementCustom.cpp?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1465254970&l=161) of chromium there seems to be some code that indeed handles some legacy call back (`V8HTMLEmbedElement.cpp` and `V8HTMLPlugInElementCustom.cpp`).

Also in [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=268945) firefox ticket this is confirmed

> why on earth are Embed/Object elements callable in the first place? [...] As far as anyone can tell, because some plug-ins do something when you call them and no one wants to break that for compat reasons...

I did not find any specification that defines this behavior. The html5 spec mentions a  [legacy caller operation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-object-caller) but does not define exactly how it works

**So as a summary: `typeof document.createElement('object')` is `"function"` because it has a `[[Call]]` internal method. And it has a `[[Call]]` internal method because of legacy reasons.**

---

If you execute this code in chrome

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  return document.createElement('object')()
})()
```

you get `undefined` as a return value. If you execute it in firefox you get an Exception

> Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code ::  :: line 1"  data: no

Interestingly `document.createElement('object') instanceof Function` is `false` and thus none of the methods from `Function.prototype` do exist on `HTMLObjectElement`.

Comment: Great in-depth answer

Answer (score 1):

As stated in https://es5.github.io/x11.html#x11.4.3, HTMLObjectElement (HTMLEmbedElement as well) has a `[[Call]]` internal property. `typeof` inspects this property to return `"function"`, which I agree is quite surprising at first.

Comment: Why does it have the `[[Call]]` property?